# Is it possible to add JavaScript to the host web from an app?

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin

Is it possible from a SharePoint-hosted app to add some JavaScript hosted on an external CDN to every page in a site (host web) without having to use a custom master page?

If not, is this something that would be achievable in an auto/provider hosted app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, without adding an AppPart to each and every page on the host web. This does not seem like a good solution in any way, but it is what comes to mind as the only possibility since you can't use Delegate Controls in SharePoint apps

Comment: Thanks. So I'm guessing that as far as the app marketplace goes, the intention is not to build apps that can change behaviour on a site wide basis? Shame, if so.

Comment: Well, that is one of the Big disadvantages with the app model! It is really a shame, but it is in most related to microsofts new strategy of stopping developers from writing code that interfers with SharePoint. But be assured, there is a whole community of SP developers trying to find workarounds for the biggest obstacles in the app model!